# Setting an Authorization header after a ForwardAuth in Traefik

Tags: traefik

I'm moving from Nginx to Traefik as the reverse-proxy of a Docker Swarm.

Currently, each request coming with a Bearer Token is sent to an authentication service (microservice running in the Swarm) which sends back a JWT when auth is correct. I then need to use this JWT in the Authorization header to the request can be sent to the service it targets.

The current setup with Nginx:

```
auth_request /auth;
auth_request_set $jwt $upstream_http_jwt;
proxy_set_header "Authorization" "jwt $jwt";
```

Can this approach be done with Traefik ForwardAuth directly or do I have to add a middleware to create this header once the request has been authenticated ?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if your authentication service can return the JWT in the `Authorization` header of its response. Set the [`authResponseHeaders`](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/forwardauth/#authresponseheaders) option of the ForwardAuth middleware to `Authorization`.

> The authResponseHeaders option is the list of headers to copy from the authentication server response and set on forwarded request, replacing any existing conflicting headers.

E.g.

```
http:
  middlewares:
    auth:
      forwardAuth:
        address: "http://your_auth_server/auth"
        authResponseHeaders:
          - "Authorization"
```